# We use SVN in our company. My whole team wants us to deploy by copying everything, everytime

Tags: php, git, svn, deployment, project-management

The current deployment process entails that we only move the differences between the current SVN revision and the SVN revision of the last deployment, which works flawlessly in my project.

Other projects complain from this method and want to deploy everything, move every file from the development environment to other environments like testing, staging, or live.

The Java team lead and the PHP team lead agree on this. I am a PHP developer and find this way inefficient, and useless. We don't have to use this much time and bandwidth when we decide to deploy to live by copying everything.

When we deploy using SVN differences, the server admins save a compressed file containing all of the modified files that relates to the current deployment, so it's easier to revert back when we want to.

I just want some good reasons to present to the manager of the company, who is technically aware of the problems with the deployment process, just to let him understand that when something gets messed up after it's deployed, it's because the developers didn't do it right, not because we have to deploy **everything** in order for things to work. I want to convince him that deploying using SVN is way better than deploying everything (primitive copy/paste) without relying at all on SVN.

Comment: I think deploying everything is better. Deploying only the changes since the last deployment relies on the existing live version being identical with a SVN revision. If something goes wrong on a deployment and nobody notices or if somebody does a quick fix directly on the live server (it can happen) then the deployment based on differences will probably fail.

Comment: @axiac When deploying from SVN, **It's not allowed** to do any changes on the live server without a deployment, you can do your fix quickly on the live server, if it works then you undo your change, then do your fix on SVN and deploy normally.

Comment: What do you use for updating code on server? svn up? I don't understand why you have to save "compressed file containing all of the modified files that relates to the current deployment". Using SVN you can switch to every revision you need to switch

Comment: @DmitriKadykov Yes, using SVN can switch every revision you need to swtich to, but we don't install an SVN client on the live server, due to technical limitations on some of the live server, so for consistency, server admins have created a bash script that automates the deployment to the live server, by taking a backup of all of the files that will be overwritten then deploying.

Comment: @Karim: if you allow doing quick fixes directly on the live server and you have a policy about how to do them the right way (undo, apply on the code base then deploy) then the chances are that sometime, somebody will either forget about it or do it wrong. If you want to do deployment based on differences then you better export from svn to a local directory, apply any configuration settings (if any) then use `rsync` to copy to the live server only the differences. This way it uses the minimum needed bandwidth and keeps everything is sync.

Comment: Looks like your admin invented his own CVS system. Are you sure it's stable. Are your really like the fact you need always maintain and support this? I don't know what is "technical limitations" but you should use SVN rather then invent another CVS system

Comment: @axiac Let's assume that we're not allowing any changes to be made on the live server, since we're going to introduct Vagrant so all of the development environments are the same specs, when it's being used, there will be no need for doing quick changes on the live server under any circumstances. So, if we prevented it, what would be the reason for us to abandon using SVN in our deployments?

Comment: @DmitriKadykov What the admin does is checkout the project on her PC, run an `svn up` then she does an `svn diff` between the last deployed revision and the revision that needs to be deployed, then create a backup of the list of modified files on the live server, then a secure copy of the list of modified/added files to the live server. All of these commands are done inside a single bash script.

Comment: @Karim: please see my answer. Using `svn diff` is not a solution because it compares revision `R1` with revision `R2` from its repository. The deployment script wants to update the live code which is assumed to be identical with `R1` to `R2`. But the live code is not a revision in the repository, it is not `R1`; it is just a copy of `R1`; it was identical to `R1` at some moment in time but there is no guarantee they are still identical. I would not rely on them being identical. Using `rsync` (as explained in my answer) is safer. And it only deploys the differences, as you want.

Comment: @axiac Why isn't it guaranteed that the live code is identical to `R1`?

Comment: @Karim: Unexpected situations. Something breaks at 3 AM; I am on call; I fix it quickly and go back to sleep; I don't follow the official policy and fix it directly on the live server; I promise myself I will follow the official rules first thing in the morning; next morning I forget what I did last night; or I remember about it late in the afternoon - there is plenty of time somebody that doesn't know what happened will deploy and break the server (not their fault). Want another scenario? Somebody in the IT runs a command line on the server that changes some files by mistake. `svn diff` fails

Comment: @Karim: maybe the scenarios I sketched in my previous comment seem unlikely. They are not my imagination; they are my memories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(I had to use an aswer because there was not enough space in the comments)*

Interesting question.

I guess that Java developers (as I am) are just used to deploy the whole application each time (and the same probably goes for any type of language that doesn't run from sources, as PHP does instead).

In a former company where I was employed, that was the way to release an update, and since the application WAR was more than one hundred megabytes, that always took a couple of hours for the whole process, even when just a couple of classes had changed.

In the company where I'm employed right now, instead, they put together a system that works with differences, so in a way similar to what you described (although Java class files have to be wholly replaced, of course).
I think that's a way better approach, much easier and lightweight to cope with.

Since PHP relies on source files even at runtime, I think that a difference-based approach like what you already have is better. So +1 for your current approach.

So, I think that faster deployment, easier backup and the other things you mention in your question are just enough good reasons for keeping the current approach.

Of course, it is important that a fully functional version can be produced and deployed from SVN at any time and that it can replace the corresponding delta-based version on the server without any fault (but I'm sure you already have that).

About the people that have opinions against yours: ask them to prove (with real world examples) where your approach is faulty.

*(Maybe this would find a better fit on [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)?*

Answer (score 2):

A sketch of our deployment script (we are using `Git`, using `Subversion` doesn't make any difference for the algorithm, only the actual commands are different). We are using a working copy (a local repository with `Git`) and another directory (named `export`) where the next version of the live code is prepared (kind of `staging` if you prefer):

- update the local copy of the code (it's `git pull` for `Git` or `svn update` for `Subversion`);
- cleanup the `export` directory then copy the code into it; we are using `rsync` instead of `cp` because it's easier to provide it a list of directories and files it should ignore (`.git`, `.svn` a.s.o.);
- apply any needed configuration settings to the files from the `export` directory; f.e. we don't keep the sensitive data (users, passwords) into the code stored in the repository but placeholder values; this step replaces the placeholder values with the actual users, passwords, keys a.s.o.
- do other needed fixups; f.e. we use some symlinks to points to directories that contain data uploaded by the users; in the code repositories we have empty directories for them; on the fixup phase these directories are removed from `export` then symlinks having the same names are created; the symlinks points to permanent directories, external to the web root, where the data is stored; also, we use symlinks to 3rd party libraries - they are not stored in the repo and their deployment follows a different pattern (they are usually frozen to the version they were when the project started, to avoid incompatibilities);
- use `rsync` with the appropriate parameters (`--archive` and others) to make the live version of the code identical with the version just prepared in the local `export` directory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are most likely experiencing is not because of "copying everything everytime", but actually due to releasing individual file fixes as a release instead of a an entire build as a release. The best-practice is to capture build artifacts for the entire application or application component, and once you've gotten to that point, it is irrelevant whether or not you are copying all the files, or just the files that have changed since that is now an implementation detail of your deployment software (whether that's a rudimentary file copy, FTP, rsync, or an enterprise-level tool like my company's product [BuildMaster](http://inedo.com/buildmaster)).